# Bootstrap HTML - Tabs as Radio Buttons Forms

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a bootstrap template that I am currently editing. I'm dealing with a form page, but I cannot seem to get the selected Radio Button, that is actually a tablist to POST to PHP

```
<div class="from-step-content">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bordered" role="tablist" name="selected-item">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-one">
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/1.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/1-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item One</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-two">
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/2.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/2-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item Two</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-three">
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/3.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/3-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item Three</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ui>
    </div>
```

This is to use method of POST into a PHP script, however I cannot figure out how I actually get which item has indeed been selected. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use javascript for invisble radio box input, cause you can't send to PHP HTML DOM, so you need to make manipulation with form.

So for quick help:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <div class="from-step-content">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bordered" role="tablist" name="selected-item">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-one">
                    <input type="radio" name="item" value="1" style="display:none;"/> 
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/1.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/1-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item One</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-two">
                    <input type="radio" name="item" value="1" style="display:none;"/>
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/2.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/2-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item Two</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#item-three">
                    <input type="radio" name="item" value="1" style="display:none;"/>
                    <div class="nav-tabs-icon">
                        <img src="images/3.png" alt="icon">
                        <img src="images/3-color.png" alt="icon">
                    </div>
                    <span>Item Three</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ui>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
          $('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", false);
          $(e.target).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
        })
    });
</script>
```